# Rearranging terms in equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble rearranging $t=(45+100x)/(9+15x)$ to be in terms of $x$=(some equation based on $t$). I'm stuck with $9t+15tx-45=100x$ and can't see how to separate out the $x$ or $t$ without dividing and ending up with the same or more $t's$/$x's$ then I currently have.

Comment: you are solving for $x$. Move all terms with $x$'s on one side of the equation (e.g. left side), and move all other terms on the other side. So, the next step would be $15tx-100x=45-9t$ (as already done in the answer below), then $(15t-100)x=45-9t$, could you finish from here?

Answer (score 2):

So we have $$t=\frac{45+100x}{9+15x}$$

Cross multiply to get $$9t+15xt=45+100x$$

$$15xt-100x=45-9t$$

Factor out $x$

$$x(15t-100)=45-9t$$

Divide

$$x=\frac{45-9t}{15t-100}$$

Note $t\neq \dfrac{20}{3}$ otherwise this is undefined.

Comment: I don't think they teach cross multiplication any longer, but rather "multiplying/dividing both sides" is how they currently teach.

Comment: Really? I mean in essesnse its the same thing, but I always used "swapping" and "cross multiplying" in school

Comment: Yeah, according to math Ed's at my uni, they argue it is not proper and further confusing.

Comment: I really doubt if you are doing a high level physics/math course that you would show this explicit multiplication. It's basically just implied